# Hide/Show navigation bar or directive on login and rest of the pages

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a directive for navigation bar and I want to hide that directive in login and to show the same on rest of the pages.

HTML to hide/show

```
 <div id="nav">
   <navigation></navigation>
 </div>
```

HTML with Body

```
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-cloak>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header" style="margin-right: 40px;">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: white;" href="#/">Test Service</a>
                </div>
                <div id="nav">
                    <navigation></navigation>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <ng-view></ng-view>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Directive

```
'use strict';

myapp.directive('navigation',
    function ($location, someservice) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'app/main/templates/Navigation.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                //some code
            },
            scope: {
            }
        };
    });
```

app.js

```
myapp.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $compileProvider) {
     $routeProvider.when('/main',
     {
         templateUrl: 'app/main/Main.html',
         controller: 'MainController'
     });
     $routeProvider.when('/registration/add',
     {
         templateUrl: 'app/registration/AddRegistration.html',
         controller: 'AddRegistrationController'
     });
     $routeProvider.when('/login',
     {
         templateUrl: 'app/login/Login.html',
         controller: 'AuthenticationController'
     });
     $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/main' });
 })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a top-level application controller:

```
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MyAppController" ng-cloak>
    ...
    <div id="nav" ng-show="navigation">
        <navigation></navigation>
    </div>
</body>
```

which would control the visibility of the navigation as well as any other top-level things:

```
angular.module("myapp")
    .controller("MyAppController", function($scope) {
        $scope.navigation = true; // default visibility state

        $scope.showNavigation = function(show) {
            $scope.navigation = show;
        };

        // other application-level things ...
    });
```

Then you could use it in any other controller to show/hide the navigation:

```
angular.module("myapp")
    .controller("AuthenticationController", function($scope) {
        $scope.showNavigation(false);

        // ... the rest of you code         
    });
```

or

```
    angular.module("myapp")
    .controller("MainController", function($scope) {
        $scope.showNavigation(true);

        // ... the rest of you code         
    });
```

Comment: thanks it worked...Just want to confirm that why showNavigation method is available in other controllers ? I was assuming the scope of ``MyAppController`` and ``MainController`` would be different. Could you please briefly explain ?

Comment: @Gaurav123, this happens due to the prototypical inheritance of the scopes. See the `Scope Hierarchies` section in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

Comment: Thanks!! I understood the concept now.